# how to get google query result into a string?

Tags: android

I have searched a lot and came up with this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
    String term = tv_question.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, term);
    startActivity(intent);
```

But I don't want to open my result from a browser. Is there any way that i can get the result of page 1 of google results into a string in any format.

Comment: check this [custom search api](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest)

Answer (score 0):

The way your doing it only allows you to launch the search not to get any results back you can use

> CustomSearch Api

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/customsearch/customsearch/v1/search.cse.list

from google and parse the result with Json

here is a snippet on how to use:

```
public searchQuery  {
    String key="your API key";
    String qry="Android";// your keyword to search
    URL url = new URL(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?               
            key="+key+"&cx="Replace with unique ID"&q="+ qry + 
            "&alt=json");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));

    String output;
    System.out.println(url);
    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {

        if(output.contains("\"link\": \"")){                
            String link=output.substring(output.indexOf("\"link\": \"")+
                   ("\"link\": \"").length(), output.indexOf("\","));
            System.out.println(link);
        }     
    }
    conn.disconnect();   
}
```

Happy Coding!!